# How do I render a Backbone Collection in a List and Item View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working on a contact bar which renders all contacts of a user in a html list.

What I have:

1. UserModel - This is a simple Backbone.Model with username and email
2. UserCollection - This is used as the contact list
3. ContactsView - This is the ul contact list
4. ContactView - This is a single contact model rendered as li

I am currently breaking my head about a solution how (and where) I can fetch my UserCollection and how I pass the single models down to a single ContactView item.

Specific hurdles are:

1. Where should I fetch, store the UserCollection
2. How do I render the contact list
3. How do I render the contact items
4. How do I prevent fetch({ success: callback }) from breaking my code structure

My current code is this:

entrance point:

```
// create a new instance of the contact list view
var view = new ContactsView();
// insert the rendered element of the contact list view in to the dom
$('div.contacts-body').html(view.render().el);
view.fetch({ success: view.loadContacts });
```

ContactsView:

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/conversations/contacts.html', 'collections/users', 'views/conversations/contact'],
    function($, _, Backbone, ContactsTemplate, UserCollection, ContactView) {

        var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName: "ul",

            className: "contacts unstyled",

            attributes: "",

            // I am feeling uneasy hardcoding the collection into the view
            initialize: function() {
                this.collection = new UserCollection();
            },

            // this renders our contact list
            // we don't need any template because we just have <ul class="contacts"></ul>
            render: function() {
                this.$el.html();
                return this;
            },

            // this should render the contact list
            // really crappy and unflexible
            loadContacts: function() {
                this.collection.each(function(contact) {
                    // create a new contact item, insert the model
                    var view = new ContactView({ model: contact });
                    // append it to our list
                    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
                });
            }

        });

        return ContactsView;

});
```

ContactView

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/conversations/contact.html'],
    function($, _, Backbone, ContactTemplate) {

        var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName: "li",

            className: "contact",

            attributes: "",

            template:_.template(ContactTemplate),

            initialize: function() {
                this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
                this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
            },

            render: function() {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }

        });

        return ContactView;

});
```

Could somebody help me about my four hurdles.

Good example links are welcome. I oriented my code style at the todos list unfortunatly the todos list isn't that advanced...

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/conversations/contacts.html', 'collections/users', 'views/conversations/contact'],
    function($, _, Backbone, ContactsTemplate, UserCollection, ContactView) {

        var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName: "ul",

            className: "contacts unstyled",

            attributes: "",

            events: {

            },

            initialize: function() {
                this.collection = new UserCollection();
                this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
                this.collection.fetch();
            },

            render: function() {
                // in chromium console
                console.log(this.el); // first: html, second: undefined
                console.log(this.$el); // first: html in array, second: undefined
                this.$el.empty(); // error on the called that this.$el is undefined

                this.collection.each(function(contact) {
                    var view = new ContactView({ model: contact });
                    this.$el.append(view.el);
                }.bind(this));

                return this;
            }

        });

        return ContactsView;
```

Can it be that reset is triggering this.render twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: why do you fetch the view? Backbone views do not have a fetch method..

#### 1 The correct place to fetch your UserCollection would be inside the view's initialize method:

```
initialize: function() { // ContactsView
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'otherMethodName', ...); // Bind this to all view functions
  ...
  this.collection.on('reset', this.render); // bind the collection reset event to render this view
  this.collection.fetch();
  ...
}
```

Now you fetch the contacts exactly when you need them. Next step is to render the collection.

#### 2 Binding to the reset event makes your loadContacts method obsolete and we can do that in the render function:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.empty(); // clear the element to make sure you don't double your contact view
  var self = this; // so you can use this inside the each function

  this.collection.each(function(contact) { // iterate through the collection
    var contactView = new ContactView({model: contact}); 
    self.$el.append(contactView.el);
  });

  return this;
}
```

Now you render your contactlist inside the render method, where it should be done.

#### 3 The ContactView actually looks good.

Just make the item to render itself in the initialize method, so you don't have to make useless calls in the ContactsView's render method and clutter up your code. Also bindAll here as well.

```
initialize: function() { // ContactView
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'otherMethodName', ...);
  ...
  this.render(); // Render in the end of initialize
}
```

I have no idea what you are asking in here, but I think the best way is not to use success callbacks. The collections and models trigger events whenever something is done to them, so tapping onto them is much more robust and reliable than success callbacks. [Check out the catalog of events to learn more.](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-events) The [Wine Cellar tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) by Christophe Coenraets is has an excellent example of this kind of listview-listitemview arrangement.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: Added _.bindAlls to fix the problem with this in a event bound render call. [Some info on binding this.](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. This truly makes things more clear for me :) There just seem to be two errors. 1.) this.$el is undefined 2.) render is getting called twice. I updated the initial post with the new code

Comment: undefined is caused by javascript scoping, which causes this to not always be what is expected. This can be fixed with underscore's bindAll -function. I updated my answer

Comment: and of course when you bind the render to the event, you should remove the render calls in your app entrance point code: `this.$el.append(view.render().el);` -> `this.$el.append(view.el);`

Comment: Appending DOM nodes in a loop could be a performance hit, we can render each view, then push then into DOM all together.

Comment: How to handle if we've bootstrapped models as mentioned here http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: all the code is simplified and no tested*

When I have all the elements structure defined, as you have, with all the Models, Collections and Views implemented then I implement a *Loader* which is in charge of trigger the fetching and rendering actions.

First of all I need to expose the classes definition from the outside something like this:

```
// App.js
var App = {}

// ContactsCollection.js
$(function(){
  var App.ContactsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });
});

// ContactsView.js
$(function(){
  var App.ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
});

// and so on...
```

And then I implement what I call the *Loader*:

```
// AppLoad.js
$(function(){

  // instantiate the collection
  var App.contactsCollection = new App.ContactsCollection();

  // instantiate the CollectionView and assign the collection to it
  var App.contactsView = new App.ContactsView({
    el: "div.contacts-body ul",
    collection: App.contactsCollection
  });

  // fetch the collection the contactsView will
  // render the content authomatically
  App.contactsCollection.fetch();
});
```

Another changes you have to do is configure the `ContactsView` in a way that respond to the changes in the `App.contactsCollection` because as the `fetch()` is asynchronous you can call `render()` when the collection is still not loaded, so you have to tell to the CollectionView to render it self when the Collection is ready:

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.collection.on( 'reset', this.addAll, this );
    this.collection.on( 'add', this.addOne, this );
    // ... same with 'remove'
  },

  addOne: function( model ){
    var view = new App.ContactView({ model: contact });
    this.$el.append( view.render().el );
  },

  addAll: function(){
    this.collection.each( $.proxy( this.addOne, this ) );
  }
});
```

You have to *require* your js files in the proper order:

1. App.js
2. Your Models, Collections, Views
3. AppLoad.js

With this system you obtain:

- External access to your collection in case you need to access it from another place.
- External control of the `CollectionView.el` with is better for decoupling and testing.
- The CollectionView will respond to changes in the Collection authomatically

**Note:** If you use `Router` you can move the `AppLoad.js` logic to there.

Comment: Hi, also an interesting approach. Will take a closer look later